# Configuring Multiple Dbcontext(Oracle and SQL) in entity framework core

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my project, I am dealing with two Databases (SQL and Oracle) in the entity framework core. I want to create the context of SQL and Oracle based on the configuration value in appsettings.json. Both SQL and Oracle DB table structure is the same.

I want to know if there is any way I can achieve this. Below is my sample code.

```
public class UserRepository: IUserRepository
{
    private readonly SQLDBContext _context;
    private readonly OraDbContext _contextOracle;        
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly bool _dbSelect;

    public UserRepository(SQLDBContext context, IConfiguration config, OraDbContext contextOracle, DbContext contexts)
    {
        _context = context;
        _config = config;
        _contextOracle = contextOracle;
        _dbSelect = Convert.ToBoolean(config.GetSection("DbType").GetSection("SQLDbConfigured").Value);
       
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the dbcontext is registered as the service in the startup.cs class when the application has started.

Do you mean you want to  register dbcontext according to the  appsettings.json value?

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to add below codes in startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
    //Check use which database
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration.GetSection("DbType").GetSection("SQLDbConfigured").Value))
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
        else
        {
            //code which used the Oracle
        }
```